# Listview suspend and resume

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout to work correctly in regards to a listview. I have added these lines of code before and after I have added the items, yet each item is still being displayed as I add each item.

thanks

- My code:

  ```
      Dim x As Integer

  Dim startTick As Integer = Environment.TickCount

  lstFiles.SuspendLayout()

  For x = 0 To UBound(cacheListArray)
      If cacheListArray(x) Like "*.txt" Then
          lstFiles.Items.Add(cacheListArray(x))
      End If
  Next

  lstFiles.ResumeLayout()

  MsgBox(Environment.TickCount - startTick)
  ```

I am adding 2000 items. This takes 7 seconds. I was told that it should be a lot shorter than that. Is that correct?

---

New code:

```
        Dim ListViewItemArray(-1) As ListViewItem

                ReDim Preserve ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray) + 1)
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).Text = file.Name
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).SubItems.Add(file.FullName)
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).SubItems.Add(file.Length)
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).SubItems.Add(file.CreationTime)
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).SubItems.Add(file.LastWriteTime)
            ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)).SubItems.Add(file.LastAccessTime)

        lstFiles.Items.AddRange(ListViewItemArray)
```

Nothing is being added. What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: It might help to show your code. People's ESP might be faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method.  The Suspend/ResumeLayout() methods are only appropriate for container controls whose child controls you want to move around without them getting repainted while you are doing so.  You never give ListView any child controls.

Use the Begin/EndUpdate() methods instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans. That does speed it up. 4 seconds now. Does that sound correct for 2000 items? I was told it should only take a few milliseconds. Is that information correct?

Comment: Well, you're ahead.  The next you'd do is take advantage of ListView.Items.AddRange() method so the items are added in bulk instead of one-at-the-time.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed this line of code: - ListViewItemArray(UBound(ListViewItemArray)) = New ListViewItem